# Java equivalent of HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress in c#

Tags: java, c#, migration

I am working on code migration from `.net` to `Java`.

I could find that `Request[""]` is mapped to `request.getParameter("")` and `RequestHeader[""]` is mapped to `request.getHeader("")`.

I am struck on statements which include `HttpContext` and dont know how to exactly convert them to Java.

Here is an code:

```
 `HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress`
```